# what kind of programming languages is this (imacros_scripts). that ends with .iim?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, imacros

I'm just asking about this programming language which is `.iim files` , or in another why the scripts that `iMacros` work with ?

This an example :

[image]

this is my question simple , i know this seems like BachFile , but this language i don't have any idea about it . please give me a little disc about it

Answer (score 0):

This is generated and used by the program iMacros. You can use the Ui interface to generate this files or create you own following the iMacros documentation http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference.

Comment: I think he is asking what language they use. Is the iMacro script language proprietary or is it JSON, C++, JavaScript, etc...